# Information_Schema broke after moving SQL Database

Tags: mysql

A few weeks ago I had some problem moving my MySQL database.  I copied it from one server to another.  Now there is something wrong with the privileges.

I can create users, databases etc when logged in as root, but I can't change users privileges, which is not good as I don't want to give my script route access.

The error I get is ..

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `newdatabase` . * TO  'newuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION ;


MySQL said: 

#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'newdatabase'
```

So I did some reading and it appears my information_schema might be bust.  The suggestions were to run flush tables on there which I have done via phpmyadmin and mysqladmin but this hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can You change topic name to something that might be useful to someone else?

Comment: Yeah, someone beat me to it.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible root cause:

GRANT fails, because `root@%` does not have all privileges on `newdatabase.*`.

In short, you can only grant privileges you have in the first place.

This has nothing to do with the information schema.

Check which privileges root@% has.

Comment: Ah I think you might be on to something there.  But, I can't change them as root is obviously the top level, if root can't change it, nobody can.  Can I reinstate the full privileges for root?